# Dynamically setting max_value and min_value in a Django/DRF serializer field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to validate some query params in a Django request handler. I am expecting to receive a number `n` that's bounded by a range. I'd like to validate `n` using `rest_framework.serializer`. Something like this:

```py
class NumberSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    number = serializers.FloatField(min_value=1, max_value=10)
```

However, I'd like to set `min_value` and `max_value` inside `FloatField` dynamically. Is that possible?

I can roll my own validator, but I am trying to learn DRF serializers. So far I feel like DRF serializers have a very specific purpose (validating incoming data against a model), but I want to get into the habit of using serializers for more generic validations like the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make custom validate method and min/max value there. For example

```
def validate_number(self, value):
    if value < self.get_min_value():
        return ValidationError(...)
    return value
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. Where does `get_min_value()` fetch min value from? Do you pass the min value into the constructor when you instantiate a serializer object, and set it as an instance variable?

Comment: Well. It's up to you. You want to set it dynamically so it depends on what is this `min_value` is based upon.